# Como salvar o conteúdo da minha página na url onclick?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, jsfiddle

Bom dia pessoal, gostaria de saber como posso salvar o conteúdo da minha página na url com um id único. Igual o jsfiddle.net

Por exemplo, quando você acessa pela primeira vez, ele tem a url padrão: jsfiddle.net, porém ao clicar no botão "save", ele gera essa url: https://jsfiddle.net/eh3zpcko/, e a cada clique no "save" ele conta e gera a seguinte url: https://jsfiddle.net/eh3zpcko/1/. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso sem que o usuário esteja logado.

Isso aí acima é só um exemplo.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Fazer isso não é uma tarefa tão trivial, recomendo estudar/tentar algo, e fazer perguntas mais específicas aqui.

Comment: Você pode inicialmente criar 2 tabelas, 1 como se fosse o "pai" e a outra o filho"
Ao tentar salvar, ele verifica se já existe 1 pai. se não existir, ele salva na tabela pai. Se existir, ele salva na tabela filho